# FileLocator's method toFileURL ignores empty folders

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle

With aid of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465417/unfolding-automatically-an-eclipse-plugin-jar/8478944#8478944) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792260/eclipse-how-to-programmatically-copy-a-folder-from-a-plugin-to-a-new-project-in/8792373#8792373) questions I managed to create the most of the desired file structure in a project by copying this from my plugin bundle.

```java
URL templatesURL = Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry(TEMPLATES_PATH);
File templatesFolder = new File(FileLocator.toFileURL(templatesURL).getPath());
copyFiles(templatesFolder, project, monitor);
```

I have two folders `TEMPLATES_PATH + "\test\java"` with no files in them. I want these to be created as well, but they don't. Investigations led me to the folder where OSGi extracts the contents of the bundle:

```
C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\<number>\0\.cp
```

The folders aren't being extracted! I could either create an empty file `"test\java\.touch"` or create the folders manually with

```
IFolder testFolder = project.getFolder(new Path("test"));
testFolder.create(true, true monitor);
testFolder.getFolder(new Path("java")).create(true, true monitor);
```

I can get the desired structure using one of the both ways but I would like to know: is there a way to make `FileLocator` extract the folders?

Comment: Are the empty folders in the plugin jar to start with? Jars usually leave out empty folders.

Comment: I use maven with tycho to build the plugin and pack the jar. Empty folders are included in the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the code that builds the directories is `org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile`.

I don't see any way to influence what it does with empty directories.